# Should we adopt a [self-study] tag like stats.SE in scope and approach?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

### Should we implement a [[self-study]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag in a similar way to stats.SE?

I think that curious people will be drawn to this site to find out more about big-data in general.  **My question is mainly two-fold:**

1. While I think that "How do I learn more" is too broad and should be flagged as such, there may be ways to specifically refine the question or narrow the scope so that the question becomes answerable (in a way that isn't overly opinion-based). Perhaps such a question can be limited to a specific discipline?[scope](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)
2. We may field questions that don't properly belong in either a programming, statistics, or super-user SE.  And if these questions are for coursework, is there any utility for our community to have this tag (without it solely being an academic honesty concern for the OP)? [discussion](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

Comment: For instance, [Is Data Science the Same as Data Mining?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14/is-data-science-the-same-as-data-mining) asks about learning more about Data-Mining.